# Installing play/pause and restart button in D3 race-bar-chart and enabling its interaction with the chart

Tags: javascript, d3.js

This is my HTML code.

```
<h1>Products</h1>
<div id = "Products" style = "width:100%; height: 650px"></div>
<button id = "Play/Pause">Play/Pause</button>
<button id = "Restart">Restart</button>
```

This is my JS code.

```
var i = 1;
var interval = setInterval(function(e){
    [time, row_data] = modifiedRowData(data, column_names, i);
    drawGraph();
    // increment loop
    i += 1;
    
    if (i == data.length)   interval.stop();
}, tickDuration);
```

Disclaimer: Both my HTML and JS code files are in separate locations in the drive.

I want to enable play/pause button and restart button that can interact with my race-bar-chart. If more code is needed for more understanding of the code i'll edit this post for more code.